# Debuginfo for polkit-0.115-11.el8.x86_64

Tags: systemtap, probe, debug-information, polkit

I am trying to use systemtap hooks on polkit functions, but I get an error that I need to install debuginfo. I can't find debuginfo for polkit package -
polkit-0.115-11.el8.x86_64. Does anyone know where can I find it?
Thnaks.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5plc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export DEBUGINFOD_URLS=https://debuginfod.elfutils.org/
stap [...]
```

The polkit debuginfo rpm you're looking for is available in the public UBI8 repo, and mirrored at the above debuginfod server.  See also: https://sourceware.org/elfutils/Debuginfod.html .